# React native boxShadows

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have problems with react-native. Have buttons with shadows what I must make. In CSS example all is easy for shadows:

```
background: #D3E3F2;
box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #F3F9FE, 1.5px 1.5px 2px #BDD1E4;
border-radius: 15px;
```

And, for blur effect:

```
background: #00A3FF;
box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 20px #78CEFF, inset -5px -5px 20px rgba(19, 0, 247, 0.3);
border-radius: 15px;
```

But how to do with React Native. In attach I add two images of the result that I except.

[image: Shadow effect]
[image: Blue effect]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this website, which generates the shadow styles for you automatically for both android and ios. Just copy the output to StyleSheet in react-native and it should be working fine
https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Comment: its not the same. if you see there are 2 shadow collars. top and left Is different than bottom and right

Comment: Tweek the offset once the code is added to your app and you will be able to show it only at the desired sides

Comment: can you show what you mean. sorry I really not understand